# node.js pass socket.io socket to forked process

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm wondering if there is any way to pass a socket.io socket to a forked process in node.js, or reconstruct a socket.io socket in the forked process?

```
child = require("child_process").fork("worker.js")
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    child.send("socket", socket); //this definitely fails now
})
```

Comment: how about 'cluster' module? If you want to clustering.

[This link 'socket.io' + 'express' clustering sample](https://gist.github.com/nulltask/1877289)

Comment: you can do fork using the cluster module

Answer (score 0):

## Solution : Use Redis

Im sure you will be happy to know about the existance of **socket.io-redis**

With it you will be able to send/receive events (share clients) between multiple instances of your code (processes or servers). [Read more : socket.io-redis (Github Repo.)](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis)

With this you can scale :

1. **vertically** (increase the number of threads per machine)
2. **horizontally**
   (deploy more "masters" accross more machines)

[There is an example app at github](https://github.com/h4t0n/socket.io-redis-appsample)

> This is a very simple Node.JS client/server application that shows
> how to setup Express.js, Socket.IO 1.x and socket.io-redis together.
>
> This is very useful as a starting point to understand how to scale
> Socket.IO RealTime Applications that need multiple server processes.
> Redis is used as a storage point (adapter) in order to run multiple
> socket.io instances in different processes or servers that can all
> broadcast and emit events to and from each other.